# Defining a method on current_user without it throwing a no method error on non logged in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, methods

I made a moderator method thats in the user model

```
  def mod_of_game?(guide_id)
    game_mods_relationships.exists?(game_category_id: guide_id)
  end
```

Problem is that whenever the user isn't logged in it just throws a no method error on the page.

I'll be making more user methods in the future and i can only assume i'll come across this problem every time.

I haven't tried it but i guess i could put an if else statement in the method

```
  def mod_of_game?(guide_id)
   if current_user.nil?
     #empty method
   else
    game_mods_relationships.exists?(game_category_id: guide_id)
  end
```

But I feel there is a more efficient way that i'm not aware of. I'm Building an app to learn rails better so i guess this is one of the things I just dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if no user is logged in, `current_user` will be `nil`, not an instance of the `User` class. So, there is no way to fix this inside the User model, as `current_user` is not a `User` if it is `nil`. Also, `current_user` is generally not available in the model, just in the controller and view.

What I would recommend is to add a filter in the controller, to make sure that if no user is logged in, the visitor will be redirected to the log in page. This can be done with a `before_action` filter in the controller, something like:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  ...
end
```

Otherwise you can always check if `current_user` is `nil` **before** calling `.mod_of_game?`, like so:

```
current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?
```

Comment: I cant use before filters in this case. The method is being called in if else statements inside the controller methods to add extra information to the db table if current_user is a mod.

Comment: Then the other suggestion I made (`current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?`) should work.

Comment: So basically the call becomes `nil.mod_of_game? @guide` when the user isn't logged in? and the method isn't in nil so it doesn't matter what i do to the method in the user model it wont work for non logged in users.

Comment: Posted the last comment as your new one updated. Doesn't feel like it will work for an if statement `if ((@category.save) && (current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?))`

Comment: Oh if you put it in a conditional I would rewrite as `if (@category.save && !current_user.nil? && current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide))`. The evaluation of the conditional will stop at the first `false`, so if `current_user` is `nil`, the method `.mod_of_game?` will not be called.

Comment: Thanks! I went with `(current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) unless current_user.nil?)` to see if it would work and it did! I'll change it to your last comment because it feels easier to read. I learnt how rails and ruby works that little bit more thanks to your help. :)

Comment: As a side note, you can also use `try`method, which is a little bit cleaner. This will assess whether `current_user` is truthy: `current_user.try(mod_of_game?, @guide)`

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
# It will return `nil` if user is not logged in
def mod_of_game?(guide_id)
  game_mods_relationships.exists?(game_category_id: guide_id) if current_user
end
```

Comment: This won't work as the method is inside the User model, so it will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is wrong.

---

Calling `mod_of_game?` is an [*instance method*](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/), which means it's got to be called on an instance of `User`.

By the nature of `current_user`, you wouldn't be able to call this method *unless* the user was logged in, or at least invoked.

You'll have to use all the conditions on the front-end to determine firstly whether `current_user` exists, and then to call `mod_of_game?` on it...

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide) %>
```

--

A much better way would be to either create your own *helper* method, or to use the [`.try`](http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html) method:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def mod? guide
      return false unless current_user
      current_user.mod_of_game? guide
   end
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
<% if mod? @guide %>
```

... which will return `false` if the user is not signed in, or the user is not a mod.

---

The reason the pattern is bad is because you're having to base logic on two conditions: `user signed in?` AND `are they a mod?`

What you want is a single point of logic, which will return true or false:

```
<% if current_user.try(:mod_of_game?, @guide) %>
```